# Is "this" a reserved keyword?

Tags: objective-c

I've added this code to my project:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  id  this;
```

and Xcode has colored "this" the same color as reserved words, but I cannot see this listed anywhere under lists of keywords when googling.

(the object is going to delete itself when finished, hence using this property for that purpose)

Comment: Perhaps it highlights all keywords from C/C++/Objective-C regardless of the file type (can't check now). Does it compile, or do you get errors?

Comment: Be safe, don't use `this`.  When it come to keywords, if in doubt: don't.  While it might be "safe" to use now, there's just too much of a chance that sometime in the future it may no longer be.

Comment: As I understand it, it's not technically reserved, but it's a predefined word and it'd be very unsafe to use it.  Don't.

Comment: I've changed its name  but I was curious as I couldn't' find it listed anywhere.